# Checking if Virtual Machine is restarting using logic apps

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use resource event occurs from a Microsoft tutorial. I know how to detect if a subscription is deleted or created. I cant find a way to detect if a virtual machine i am using restarts

Comment: Include a [mcve]

Comment: I am running a python program on my virtual machine.  If the VM restarts i need to go restart the program.  I just need an alert to warn me.

Comment: You don't show any attempt to try anything, or what code you currently have. That means no help can come.

Answer (score 0):

We have a document that explains the different kinds of reboots. In that doc you will find a link to the Activity Logs which you can use to find when a VM reboots among other actions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/understand-vm-reboot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-logs-overview