# Checking if Python code is still running on VM

Tags: python, virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

I am running a Python script on Azure VM. This code is on a continuous `while` loop and is designed to never stop. If the VM resets or the program randomly stops I have no way to know that. How can I make a logic app that will tell me if the program stops?

I would like to receive an email notifying me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if Virtual Machine is restarting using logic apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282150/checking-if-virtual-machine-is-restarting-using-logic-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you're asking isn't really the right way to do this.

You should develop and deploy your app so that it's enabled/run by Windows either in a VM as you have now or an Azure App Service.

Meaning, build and deploy it so it can just restart after a crash rather than worrying about constantly checking it.  Of course, it need to run reliably as well.

And again, Azure Services don't just randomly crash so that's really one of the last edge cases you should be concerned about.